# node command freezes Powershell, but works fine in Command Prompt

Tags: node.js, powershell

`node` command freezes Powershell, but works fine in Command Prompt as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I'm new to node.js and today I've installed node-v16.16.0-x64.msi from
https://nodejs.org/en/
and during installation checked to include Chocolatey and after it finished installation I took this screenshot:
[image]

`npm` command works fine in both Powershell and Command Prompt, but it gives a warning in both (but that's another issue):

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
```

Comment: [PowerShell ISE isn't meant for running typical interactive console programs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31595280/3439404).

Comment: @JosefZ I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbQPGgQqKf4&ab_channel=TubeMint) about node.js installation and Powershell worked fine there.

Comment: `PowerShell` and `PowerShell-ISE` are different (and the latter is considered _obsolete_).

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks, `node` indeed works is PowerShell (unlike in PowerShell-ISE).